# python xml structure iteration not keeping variables within for loops

Tags: python, xml

I'm using the following code to iterate through an xml file, I want to extract the folder structure.
Ideally I'd like a list in which each element would have the following structure:
top_folder, first_folder, page_view
Alternatively a dictionary with top_folder and page_view would also work for me.
The problem I'm having is that if I try to print the variable from the previous for loop, it doesn't work. Which I don't understand, as I'm use it in other parts of the script.
The code is:

```
top = ""
for first_iter in root_navigation:
    for second_iter in first_iter:
        for top_folder in second_iter:
            if top_folder.text and top_folder.text.strip():
                #print top_folder.text
                top == top_folder.text
            for first_folder in top_folder:
                if first_folder.text and first_folder.text.strip():
                    #print "  "+first_folder.text
                    first = first_folder.text
                for page_view in first_folder:
                    if page_view.text and page_view.text.strip():
                        #print "     "+page_view.text
                        print top+":"+first+":"+page_view.text
```

So far I've tried the above code, and directly printing the top_folder.text and first_folder.text in the last if.

The only output I manage to get, the commented prints is something like:
Top Folder
  First Folder
    Page View
  First Folder
    Page View
.....

Which doesn't really work as I'd like to have a list or something I could match later with the view name and get the top folder for it.

Any ideas of why the variables are not getting across the for loops or another way I could do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You do know you're using `top == top_folder.text` when you should be using `top = top_folder.text`, right?

Comment: What about providing an example of XML to work with. Also showing expected output would help.

Comment: doh! @cwallenpoole, thanks! that was the problem. Can't believe I missed that one....